# python object oriented programming type:list object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
class y():
    def __init__(self,favourite_channels = [""]):

        self.favourite_channels= favourite_channels
    def favourite_channels(self,i):
        print("Ur Favourite Channel=",i)
        self.favourite_channels.append(i)
x = y()
print("""*******************

1. Favourite Channel
press q to the exit
*******************""")

while True:

    a = input("Select : ")
    if a=="1":
        channels=input("Your fav channels use , to the split")
        addable_channels =channels.split(",")
        for i in addable_channels:
            x.favourite_channels(i)


    elif a=="q":
        break
    else:
        print("İnvalid Number")
```

Comment: Please make sure your code is formatted correctly and provide a *[mcve]*. In addition, code only questions are not helpful.

Comment: Yes, `list object is not callable` is exactly the output I expect from this code. What did you want to happen?

Comment: wanted to send this i to my functian and then add it ass a favourite channel . Its just part of my code  so wanted to add it as a favourite channel and ı will write  __str__ function will output my favourite channels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you but braces end of a list (x.favourite_channels is list), then you get such error.
if you want i'th element of list x.favourite_channels you should write x.favourite_channels[i-1] instead.